# Create multiple copies of a singlle file in java

Tags: java

i have a fileserver and client and want to rename files, if they already exists in downloadfolder. what is the best way to do that? I tried that code but it always create one copy and the next copy overwrites the first one.

```
            File f = new File(FILE_DIR + fileName);

            if(f.exists()) { 

                System.out.print("file already exists");

                fileName = "copy_of_" + fileName;

            }
```

Comment: And why do you think that happens?

Comment: If you want to rename the files, you can use [`File#rename`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) and if you want to copy the file, you can use [`Files.copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)

Comment: but if i have ex. 5 copies the filename changes so i have to test on copies but i dont know how to make an iteration like in php

Comment: Basically, you need a loop which uses a numerical index and continues loop until either a max value is reached or `File#exists` for the given `FILE_DIR + fileName + index` is `false`

Comment: right, as Johan said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269339/create-multiple-copies-of-a-singlle-file-in-java/28269410#28269410

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class you declare :

```
private static int X = 0;
```

and then change the code to this:

```
File f = new File(FILE_DIR + fileName);

        if(f.exists()) { 

            System.out.print("file already exists");

            fileName = "copy_of_ " + X + fileName;
x++;

        }
```

so everytime the x will increase by 1, (x++), so they will have different names.

Comment: do you mean: and then.. in a while loop?

Comment: I just added the X in the filename which represents a number, then x will increase by one everytime so the filenames will never have the same name :)

Comment: ok thanks a lot. i tried it that way also but  i didnt tried to create a static variable first so i got endless output "file exists". btw you should edit your code because your X var is first big and then small. also in filename X will not be interpretet as a var because its inside the "". thanks again :D